# XCode 5: How to Debug? Get the line of the error? NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to debugging in XCode 5. **I was wondering how to get the "line" that throws this error?**

```
2014-04-28 09:09:30.917 someApp[23426:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x23b2068'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the navigation go to Breakpoint navigation , bottom left there is + sign , choose 'Add exception breakpoint' and the code will break on the line where it crashes

Answer (score 1):

You should really follow the WWDC videos on debugging , for now this would help you to get the line number ,

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html