# Managed object context crashes during save

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My application calls the core data and manages the object with a nsfetchedresultscontroller and build a tableview with the results. The tableview cells when tapped push to a detail view where i can change the properties of the objects and save.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  NSError *error;
  if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to fetch data");
  }
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
  if (_fetchedResultsController) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
  }
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ZTExercise" inManagedObjectContext:[[ZTDataManager sharedDataManager] mainContext]];
  fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]];

  _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[ZTDataManager sharedDataManager].mainContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionTitle" cacheName:nil];
  _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

  return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailExerciseSegue"]) {
    ZTExerciseDetailController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
    ZTExercise *exercise;
    if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
      selectedIndexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      exercise = self.searchResults.allValues[selectedIndexPath.section][selectedIndexPath.row];
    } else {
      selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
      exercise = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    }
    controller.exercise = exercise;
  }
}
```

In the tableview controller, there is also a search bar which pushes the object the same view when tapping the cells.

The actions that trigger the crash are

```
[self applyCustomizationToAlertView:[ZTAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Add record" message:@"Enter new lifting weight (lbs)" cancelTitle:@"Cancel" otherTitle:@"Add" contentView:addRecordView completion:^(BOOL cancelled, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    if (cancelled) {
      return;
    }
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
      if (addRecordTextField.text && [addRecordTextField.text length]) {

        ZTExerciseRecord *newRecord = [ZTExerciseRecord insertObjectInContext:[ZTDataManager sharedDataManager].mainContext];
        newRecord.score = [addRecordTextField.text integerValue];
        [self.exercise insertObject:newRecord inERecordsAtIndex:0];

        NSError *error;
        if (![[ZTDataManager sharedDataManager].mainContext save:&error]) {
          NSLog(@"Failed to save data");
          return;
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[self.sections indexOfObject:ZTSectionNameLift]]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        return;
      }
    }
  }]];
```

and

```
self.exercise.eRecords = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:[self.exercise.eRecords sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:NO]]]];
```

The crash occurs when I search for an object through the search bar, and if the cell tapped is not the first entry of the searchtableview. It pushes to the detail view, but when i perform an action which involves changing a relation or saving the context it crashes with this code

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0] with userInfo (null)
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

All help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

**Update 1**
The error says that I'm inserting something at index 1, but in all my code the only part that access an index other than 0 is in the table viewdata source which is consistent with the number of objects fetched.

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  if (self.recordTableView == tableView) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  if (self.recordTableView == tableView) {
    return [self.exercise.eRecords count];
  }
  return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *cellIdentifier;
  UITableViewCell *cell;
  if (self.recordTableView == tableView) {
    cellIdentifier = @"ZTExerciseLogCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
      cell = [[ZTExerciseLogCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
  }
  [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
  return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ZTExerciseLogCell"]) {
    ZTExerciseLogCell *newCell = (ZTExerciseLogCell *)cell;
    newCell.record = self.exercise.eRecords[indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

ZTExerciseController -> push -> ZTExerciseDetailController

Another thing I noticed is the error occurs while in a class called ZTExerciseDetailController but in the crash log the error says it occurs in the ZTExerciseController

This crash log belongs to the insertion of a object inside the mutableorderedset of an exercise

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101cc3495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001017c399e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c7be3f -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 175
    3   ZetaProject                         0x0000000100004524 -[ZTExerciseController configureCell:atIndexPath:] + 404
    4   ZetaProject                         0x0000000100005a13 -[ZTExerciseController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] + 819
    5   CoreData                            0x0000000102047c3b -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 4187
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101d18d9c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c7b51d _CFXNotificationPost + 2381
    8   Foundation                          0x00000001001547fa -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
    9   CoreData                            0x0000000101f7348a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 74
    10  CoreData                            0x0000000101ff9c8b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 331
    11  CoreData                            0x0000000101f6f243 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1875
    12  CoreData                            0x0000000101ff9d25 __90-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _processEndOfEventNotification:]_block_invoke + 85
    13  CoreData                            0x0000000101f90c7b developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 107
    14  CoreData                            0x0000000101f90bc4 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 132
    15  CoreData                            0x0000000101f9364b -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _processEndOfEventNotification:] + 123
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101d18d9c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c7b51d _CFXNotificationPost + 2381
    18  Foundation                          0x00000001001547fa -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
    19  Foundation                          0x0000000100149460 -[NSUndoManager _postCheckpointNotification] + 92
    20  Foundation                          0x0000000100149242 -[NSUndoManager _endUndoGroupRemovingIfEmpty:] + 95
    21  Foundation                          0x00000001001985ff __NSFirePerformWithOrder + 339
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c8edc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c8ed37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c6e438 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101c6dd83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103471f04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010059fe33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    28  ZetaProject                         0x000000010002a6a3 main + 115
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001030f35fd start + 1
)
```

**Update 2**

Ok, I think have isolated the problem. When a change is made on the exercise object apparently it calls the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate (Update type) function of:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
  switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
      [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
      [self configureCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
      break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                              arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                              arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      break;
  }
}
```

Then it calls the configureCell:atIndexPath: function:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  ZTExerciseCell *newCell = (ZTExerciseCell *)cell;
  ZTExercise *exercise;
  if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive && [self.searchResults count]) {
    exercise = self.searchResults.allValues[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
  } else {
    exercise = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  }
  newCell.exercise = exercise;
}
```

But the problem is that during this the search tableview is active and gets the wrong object. How can i validate when it is coming from delegate fetch results function or the tableviewcell function?, or is there a better way to manipulate a search tableview with the nsfetchresultscontroller?

Comment: This is not how you do core data changes when using an `NSFetchedResultsController`. You need to use the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Second line of log says that you are trying to access index of array that doesn't exist.Maybe you have forgotten to initialize it or something.
Check [XCode 5: How to Debug? Get the line of the error? NSInvalidArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334759/xcode-5-how-to-debug-get-the-line-of-the-error-nsinvalidargumentexception/23334817#23334817) and track down on which line your code crashes

Comment: No, it says the range of the array goes from 0 to 0. i.e. it exists but it is empty.

Comment: As @wootage said, you are accessing an index that does not exist.  Use the debugger to find the line it crashes and test the array. The array is empty and you are trying to access index 1 which is the second item in an empty array.  That is an error.

Comment: The only time in my code that I access an index other than 0 is during the data source function of the table view. which are numbered with number of objects inside the ordered set

Answer (score 0):

```
NSFetchedResultsController * consultMessageFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[[WYCoreDataStorage shareStore] coreDataHelper] mainContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:entityName];
```

`cacheName:entityName  这个设置了cache,导致的，如果设置了，一定要不用的时候移除掉`。

苹果文档如下：：
**IMPORTANT**
If you are using a cache, you must call deleteCacheWithName: before changing any of the fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptors. You must not reuse the same fetched results controller for multiple queries unless you set the cacheName to nil.